# Laravel `jobs` таблица весит очень много

Tags: mysql, laravel

недавно столкнулся с проблемой: на хостинге в базе данных таблица `jobs` и `failed_jobs` весят очень много. И из-за этого иногда у меня появляется ограничение по размеру базы данных. Скриншот прилагаю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С чем это связано, идей нет. Если нажать на кнопку "показать всё", то у меня в таблице `jobs` записей 30, не больше. Откуда такой размер??

У меня есть cron запись, которая каждую минуту выполняет один скрипт через job'ы, может с этим как-то связано?

Answer (score 1):

Во первых. В чём причина использования таких костылей для job??? Все job должны выполняться через слушатели. `php artisan queue:work ...`.

Далее. Если надо чтобы данные скрипты хранились в фоне. То для этого есть supervisor и другие демоны. (в доке по умолчанию предлагают использовать его)

В третьих при выполнении оператора `delete` (а вы их так удаляете скорее всего), не очищается место на диске. Не задумывались почему если вставить запись новую, то всегда вставляется с новым id, а не с тем которого не хватает?

Поэтому есть такая вещь в mysql  `OPTIMIZE TABLE tablename` позволяет решить данный вопрос. В pgsql `vacuum`

Comment: Supervisor на хостинг установить возможности нет, у меня на сервере каждую минуту выполняется cron запись, которая запускает `php artisan schedule:run` (из документации по ларавель). Там я запускаю обработку очередей `$schedule->command('queue:work')->cron('* * * * *')->withoutOverlapping();`. И еще я там их раз в сутки перезапускаю. И так же там же я запускаю команду, которая уже оперирует job'ами. ну, то есть они запускаются через команду, а обрабатываются `queue:work`, как и положено

Comment: А id да, там 350000 id есть. В ручную я не удаляю их, Laravel сам их выполняет и убирает. Не совсем понял, из-за чего это и как это предотвратить?

Comment: @Colorkat попробуйте выполнить команду OPTIMIZE TABLE jobs в sql

Comment: Это не помогло, jobs так же 3гб весит

Comment: Так есть еще какие-нибудь идеи? Таблица всё также спустя некоторое время начинает увеличиваться в размерах. В чём проблема, я не понимаю

Comment: Выложите код вашего Job.. Скорее всего там косяк.

Comment: @Colorkat пока не знаю. Надо смотреть весь код, но попробуйте сделать ребилд таблицы: `ALTER TABLE jobs Engine=InnoDB;`

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего проблема в реализации Job-а. Возможно вы при создании передаете в конструктор большой объем данных. Далее эти данные сериализуются в базу.

Comment: Да, в конструкторах довольно большой массив данных. Что с этим можно сделать? У меня цепочка из 3х job'ов. В одном данные достаются особым образом из БД, во втором они обрабатываются, потом передаются в третий, где обработанные данные вставляются в БД

Comment: Попробуйте получать данные непосредственно в методе handle() Job-а, а не передавать их в конструктор. Всегда есть иная реализация любой задачи... возможно стоит пересмотреть вашу последовательность из трех джобов и сделать иначе.